# Error answering a question using Bayes Theorem - Conditional probability?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

The question is made of 3 parts, 2 of which require the use of Bayes' formula:

> (a) At a clinic for patients with suspected malaria, 89 out of a total of 300
> were found to actually be infected with malaria.
> Use this information to estimate P (I = infected), where I represents
> the malaria infection status (infected or not infected) of a randomly
> selected patient attending this clinic.

a) is straightforward, giving $$P(I)=89\div300\approx0.297$$

> (b) There are various blood tests that can be used to diagnose malaria. One
> particular test is ‘paracheck’, which is a rapid dipstick test. Let
> R = paracheck positive for malaria.
> For patients at this clinic, it is estimated that
> P (R | I = infected) = 0.910 and P (R | I = not infected) = 0.137. Use
> your answer to part (a) and Bayes’ theorem to estimate
> P (I = infected | R), the probability that when paracheck is positive for
> malaria, a patient at this clinic is infected with malaria.

The formula I used for this is $$P(R│I=infected) \times P(I=infected) \div P(R)$$

To calculate P(R)

$$P(R) = P(R│I)\times P(infected)+P(R│I not infected)\times P(not infected)$$

$$0.910 \times 0.296 + 0.137 \times 0.704 = 0.365808$$

$$(0.910 \times 0.296) \div 0.365808 = 0.7363425622$$

giving approximately a 73.6% chance a patient who tested positive with Paracheck is infected with malaria

> (c) An alternative diagnosis method is blood microscopy. Let
> M = microscopy positive for malaria.
> For patients at this clinic, it is estimated that
> P (M | R, I = infected) = 0.519 and
> P (M | R, I = not infected) = 0.207. Calculate the probability that a
> patient at this clinic who tested positive for malaria by both paracheck
> and microscopy is infected with malaria.

To check if my calculations for b) were correct, I used the same formula and logic for this part

$$0.519 \times 0.296 + 0.207 \times 0.704 = 0.299352$$

$$(0.519 \times 0.296) \div 0.299352 = 0.5131884871$$

Meaning that theres only a 51.3% probability that a patient that tests positive for both paracheck and microscopy also has malaria.

This doesn't make sense to me based on my answer to part b) which makes me think I am making a foolish error.

Can anyone see where my mistake is?

Comment: Can you re-format your math expressions in [Mathjax](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated)?

Comment: @Zhanxiong
Will have a look now

Comment: @Zhanxiong
Is that a bit clearer now?

Comment: Thank you.  It is much clearer.  I made further edits by replacing your code blocks with quotation blocks.

Comment: You are not conditioning on $R$ and should compute $$P(M|R)=P(M|R,I)P(I|R)+P(M|R,I^c)P(I^c|R)$$

Comment: @Xi'an
Can you explain it a little it more please? I don't see entirely what you mean

Comment: Since this is a homework/self-study question, I'd rather not...